# How do I remove 1-pixel edge on right side of my page?

Tags: html, css, que

I'm having a difficult time isolating a 1-pixel edge that appears on the right-hand side of my site. It happens at different window sizes on Chrome and Safari, and I can't seem to figure out what's causing it, or whether it's actually something completely unavoidable with my setup.

**Website:** www.husamelfaki.net

Thanks very much if you can help in advance, really appreciate it.
Husam

EDIT: Removed sensitive password detail, now that the question's been answered. Thank you.

Comment: Most StackOverflow users won't click on scary off-site links.  Post the code, or at the very least, add a screenshot of your issue.

Comment: what do you mean by 1-pixel edge?

Comment: Just FYI, it's not very wise to post password to your site, you are just enabling hackers to try to figure out how to get into your admin space and ruin your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from every element on the right side like this one:

```
<div style="line-height: 0 !important; 
     font-size: 0px !important;
     position: absolute;
     left: 49.93055555555556%;
     top: 0px; opacity: 1;"
     class="thumb grid-item masonry-thumbs-item masonry-content_4qnsts4j5-item masonry-content_4qnsts4j5-item-1 remove-gutter-yes masonry-span6"
     data-thumb-src="http://www.husamelfaki.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/ntc5_thumb_2.jpg">
```

Its width is 50% but the element's left side isn't placed at `50%`. Set the left to half the width with the CSS style rule `left: 50%;`.

And I suggest you to use flex-boxing which is perfect for this kind of pages.

Comment: Great answer – actually it's the right code to fix my problem.

The thumbnails are automatically generated and positioned by Semplice (my wordpress theme), so now I'm specifically targeting these individual thumbnails and adding the fix on top. What I'd preferably like to do is find the source that's outputting this odd number, and correct the code from there. 

If you can help me figure that out I'd be very impressed and grateful, but understand if this is too much. I've now followed up with the theme provider to see if there's a better way to target these elements and fix at the source.

Comment: I've never used Wordpress so I think I won't be of any help. I don't know how this could occur. I think your best shot would be to create a new thread now you've located the issue. Be sure to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before and included as much information as possible (plugins, template, javascript codes and so on...). Including a snippet will also increase your chances. And finally, include the `Wordpress` tag into your question, this will allow Wordpress experts to assist you.